Rust- SFCGAL - retrieve the distance from the straight skeleton?
Using the following code in rust SFCGAL,
let coords_polygon = vec![vec![
                            // Exterior ring
                            (0., 0.),
                            (0., 5.),
                            (8., 5.),
                            (8., 10.),
                            (10., 10.),
                            (10., 0.),
                            (0., 0.),
                    ]];
    
let polygon_3d = CoordSeq::Polygon(coords_polygon).to_sfcgal().unwrap();
let out = polygon_3d.straight_skeleton_distance_in_m().unwrap();

I can't retrieve the distance in M to only keep the points in the middle of the shape.
One alternative is to take every point and discard any existing point in the original shape but it's not that efficient.
Exporting to wkt (.to_wkt() ) is an option but you retrieve a string : inefficient.
Exporting to coordinates:
let hh: CoordSeq<(f64, f64)> = out.to_coordinates().unwrap();

and the distance is lost.
So, I need to get the distance. But don't know how.
Any clue ?
Thanks
